# Unique ID outside of Message Body in Service Broker

Tags: sql, sql-server, service-broker

We are trying to implement a system that look like this diagram:

[image]

In step 1, the User Application will call a Stored Procedure to call the service (begin the dialog conversation). And we need an `ID` to identify that request.

After that, the User Application will start making periodical request to the Reply "Queue" using `Receive` statement with `Where` clause (I put Queue in the double quote, because in fact it doesn't really work like a queue).

Here, the problem we have is that, how can we maintain a unique ID throughout the process (step 2 and 3), and that ID is somewhere outside of Message Body, because we want to use `Where` clause of `Receive`. The `conversation_handle` could not help us, because they are different from each endpoint.

Is there any ID that persist from the begin of the dialog until `END CONVERSATION`?

Answer (score 2):

> "Periodically ask for a response for a specific request"

You cannot do that. Your application must dequeue responses and handle them, as they become available, all of them. Any architecture that attempts to poll for specific messages will fail. This is a fundamental tenet of Service Broker.

Also you do not "ask periodically" in Service Broker. You have `WAITFOR (RECEIVE ...)` exactly to replace pooling 'periodically'.

Answer (score 1):

We use this syntax:

```
BEGIN DIALOG CONVERSATION @Handle
    FROM SERVICE @InitiatorService
    TO SERVICE @TargetService
    ON CONTRACT @OnContract
    WITH ENCRYPTION = OFF;
```

The variable `@Handle` will after this statement contain a uniqueidentifier which will remain the same during the entire conversation. On the receiving end, we have this:

```
RECEIVE TOP(1)
    @Handle = [conversation_handle],
    @Type = [message_type_name], 
    @Message = [message_body]
FROM
    [TargetQueue]
```

Which get the same value for `@Handle` as was created by the sender.

We have pretty much just implemented this: http://rusanu.com/2007/12/03/resending-messages/ and it works great.